# Cannot #include <QtSvg>

Tags: c++

I am trying to include QtSvg in mainwindow.cpp but when I compile it says cannot open include files: QtSvg. I have already added this(QT += svg) in my *.pro file. May I know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After "pro" file change, it is necessary to launch **qmake**. After that it is possible to compile application.

Comment: Thank you so much. QML SVG tutorial didn't mention this at all.